# present continuous for a new habit

Tags: present-tense

Is it possible to say or write ?

Now, I am wearing my contact lenses from time to time.

or is it better to use present simple

Now, I  wear my contact lenses from time to time.

I've chosen continuous because it is a new habit  before I wore them full time.

Comment: The phrase is "from **time** to **time**" - it is always singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the present continuous with expressions like "these days", "at the moment" or "currently". I used to wear glasses but at the moment I am wearing contact lenses. Here you emphasize the fact that something has changed.

Answer (score 2):

We use **Present Progressive** if we want to emphasise that an activity...

> **1. is happening at now.**
>
> > *He is watching TV now.*
>
> **2. differs from what is expected or usual** (PS - PP)
>
> > *He usually gets up at 7, but this week he is getting up at 8.*
>
> **3. is disliked by the speaker or evokes ambivalent feelings.**
>
> > *He is always listening to that stupid disco record!*

If you try to fit your sentence into these rules, you'll find out that it would be possible to use it in PP, but there's an adverb of time in the sentence (from time to time) that is a synonym for *sometimes* and that AoT usually goes with Present Simple.

On the other hand, *now* and *from time to time* in the same sentence are a bit erroneous. Please consider the following alternatives:

> **Now I am wearing my contact lenses.** (Now I am having to because I would not see anything but vaguely otherwise.)
>
> **I wear my contact lenses from time to time.** (I wear them, even though I don't need them day in day out.)

Comment: But if I want to say that there is a change   can I say      Before I  always wore my contact lenses but now I am wearing them less and less

Comment: Then you should say *Even if I always wore my contact lenses, now I wear them less and less.*

Comment: so I can not use the continuous  why ? It differs from what is usual because it will be  a new habit ,Is it because this new habit is definitive

Comment: If you want to describe an action as a new trend (or an annoying habit), then you can use Present Continuous. Consider the following: *Are you still working for the same company?* *More and more people are becoming vegetarian.* You also use PC if you want to express annoyance at repeated actions: *Why are you always asking me questions?*

Comment: ok but how to formulate that Now  I am not wearing my contact lenses as I used to do before  (without any adverb of time )  correct in that way

Comment: I used to wear my contact lenses, now I don't.

Comment: I don 't understand you say it is ok for a new trend to use present continuous The fact of not wearing my contact lense is new trend

Comment: If you got lost, I advise you to brush up on the different use of tenses. Further discussion violates the basic rules of this site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75665/discussion-between-user5577-and-marcus).